# SMPP Submit SM timeout in Bulk SMS

Tags: go, sms, smpp

I'm using this package https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fiorix/go-smpp/smpp to handle bulk sms sending. After sending like 1,000 SMS's, I get SMPP timeout error and the sending process stops. How can I resolve this provided that I'm developing a Bulk SMS platform that uses SMPP 3.4

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt receive the SUBMIT_SM_RESP , you should check on SMPP server side.